# C++ pointer parameter trouble

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters

I am a beginning programmer writing a graphical game using SDL. The function that splits a tile-sheet into sections or "clips" and puts it into a array and the function that draws specific "clips" onto the screen are not working as intended.

```
void split_tilesheet(int width, int height, int space, Entity * ent){
    std::cout << "Splitting Tileset...";

    int t_width = (width / SPR_W);
    int t_height = (height / SPR_H);
    int numTiles = (t_width * t_height);

    ent = new Entity [numTiles + 1];
    if( ent == NULL){
        err("!failed to alloc!");
    }else{
        std::cout << "allocated"<< std::endl;
    }
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < t_width; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < t_height; j++){

            ent[count].bounds.x =  i * SPR_W;
            ent[count].bounds.y = j * SPR_H;
            ent[count].bounds.w = SPR_W;
            ent[count].bounds.h = SPR_H;
            ent[count].id = ent[i].x + ( ent[i].y * t_width);
            count++;
        }
    }
}

void draw_room(char tiledata[MAP_MAX_X][MAP_MAX_Y], Entity * ent){
SDL_Rect bounds;
    for(int x  = 0; x < MAP_MAX_X; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < MAP_MAX_Y; y++){

            if(tiledata[x][y] == '0' || tiledata[x][y] == ' ' || tiledata[x][y] == '\n' ){
                draw_img(x * SPR_W , y * SPR_H, tiles, bounds, ent[0].bounds); 
            }
            if(tiledata[x][y] == '1'){
                draw_img(x * SPR_W , y * SPR_H, tiles, bounds, ent[1].bounds);
            }
        }           
    }
}

class Entity
{
public:
    SDL_Rect bounds;
    SDL_Surface* sprite;
    int id;
    int x;
    int y;
    int w, h;
 };
```

I was trying to use pointers to dynamically allocate the memory at runtime.
The program compiles, but segfaults. gdb says that the segfault is due to the draw_room() function, but I cannot figure out why. The pointer I was passing to the draw_room function was:

```
Entity * floor0_clips = NULL;
```

This didn't work either

```
Entity * floor0_clips;
```

Please help...

Comment: Each call to that function is leaking memory. And `new` throws an exception when it fails, so checking for a null pointer is redundant.

Comment: So how would I fix the memory leak? add delete [] ent at the end of the function?

Comment: Use a vector instead of something you have to manage yourself. And use a reference if you mean for the changes to `ent` to propagate to the caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ uses pass-by-value (unless you specify pass-by-reference), which you didn't.

A variable in a function is a copy of the argument given. For example:

```
int func(int x)
{
    x = 5;
}

int main()
{
    int y = 6;
    func(y);
    // here, `y` is still `6`
}
```

Your case is fundamentally the same as this. You send `floor0_clips` to a function, the function updates a copy of it, leaving the original unchanged.

To use pass-by-reference instead, put the `&` symbol just before the variable name in the function's parameter list, i.e. in your case `Entity * &ent` . Do not change anything in the code which calls the function;  it is the function's parameter list declaration that decides whether the value is passed by value or by reference.

NB. You appear to be allocating too many Entities anyway (why the `+ 1`?).